# SO Stack snippet console displays <input></input> is this a bug?

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

Is there a reason why the Stack snippet console displays `<input>` elements within an array with an end tag? I noticed this behavior when posting this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43029524/2813224).

[image: From my answer shows snippet console displaying the <code><input></code> element with an end tag <code></input></code>]

[image: This is a more simplified version of the answer]

Both Chrome and Firefox consoles on PC display this answer correctly (i.e. sans `</input>` end tag). Also, just in case I am mistaken about how an `<input>` tag should be, I found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Live_example):

> **Tag omission**  Must have a start tag and must not have an end tag.

I have scoured SO extensively because I expected this issue to have been reported already, but couldn't find anything remotely similar.

Here's a Stack Snippet showing this in action:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  console.log(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input')));
};
```

```html
<input name="example" type="radio" value="1">
<input name="example" type="radio" value="2">
```

Comment: [Oddly enough, this used to happen in Firefox's web inspector.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30847587/why-does-firefox-display-empty-elements-with-closing-tags-in-its-web-inspector)

Comment: _"Both Chrome and Firefox consoles on PC display this answer correctly."_, So, what browser are you using? Also, for me, it's logging with `</input>`.

Comment: @Cerbrus There's 3 consoles* that I could use. 1. Developer Tools from Chrome - using Chrome, 2. Firebug from Firefox using Firefox, and 3, Stack snippet  from SO using Chrome or Firefox. *(I left out MS browsers and Opera out intentionally). When using the 3rd option the `</input>` is evident.

Comment: @BoltClock if you and Cerbrus don't know much about this behavior, then I can safely assume this is a bug.